# Why A Basic Solution Is A Vertex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, simplex

A basic solution is a vector with $n$ components ($n=$ the number of variables), in which $m$ of them ($m=$ the number of functional constraints) are positive and the remaining ($n-m$) components are zero.

How does this implies that it must be a vertex point?

Comment: A small but important point: $n-m$ of the components must equal 0 (these are the *nonbasic* variables); the remaining $m$ of them *may* be positive (these are the *basic* variables) -- but they may also equal 0.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the LP is written in standard form (all functional constraints are $\le$, all decision variables are $\ge 0$), then there are a total of $m+n$ constraints ($m$ functional and $n$ non-negativity), and each constraint corresponds to a variable (either a slack variable or a "regular" variable).

A basic solution is the solution you obtain by:

- choosing $m$ of the constraints (out of the total of $m+n$ functional and non-negativity constraints)
- setting them to equalities
- forcing the $n-m$ variables that do *not* correspond to your $m$ constraints to 0, and
- solving the resulting system of equations for the $m$ variables that *do* correspond to your $m$ constraints.

Since you are solving a system with $m$ equations and $m$ unknowns, there is a single unique solution (assuming there's nothing funny going on like degeneracy), and that is your basic solution. Graphically, the basic solution is a vertex of the feasible region because it is the single point that is on the boundary of all $m$ of those constraints.

Comment: Note that if the $m$ by $m$ basis matrix is singular, then even if you can solve the system of equations the solution is not considered to be a basic solution.  Degeneracy is a different problem, which occurs when there are multiple sets of $m$ constraints that give the same basic solution.  This can only happen if one or more of the basic variables takes on the value 0.

Comment: The basic solution correspond to the vertex in the higher dimensional plane that is formed by adding the slack and converting the inequalities into equations. am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is, the $m$ positive components identify the vertex point, which is the exact solution of those $m$ equations.